# Can the apex tag be renamed to avoid confusion with oracle-apex

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

There is a tag [apex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apex) that refers to the Salesforce Apex language.  There is also an Oracle product called APEX that has the tag [oracle-apex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-apex). However, I would estimate that about half of questions tagged [apex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apex) should really be [oracle-apex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-apex).

I would suggest the the [apex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apex) tag should be renamed to `salesforce-apex` or perhaps `apex-lang` to avoid this mistake?

Comment: We should also look at the [apex-code tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apex-code): "A proprietary Java-like programming language for the Force.com Platform, not to be confused with Oracle's Application Express [tag:oracle-apex]". Seems like it should be a synonym.